# Algebraic long division with package? in math mode? Able to handle negative exponents?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I need to express a/(a+a^(-1)) - a^(-1)/(a+a^(-1)) with long division, for a mathematical lemma. I have done the operation on paper and have the come to the following:

eq1: a/(a+a^(-1)) = 1 - a^(-2) + a^(-4) - a^(-6) + ...

and

eq2: a^(-1)/(a+a^(-1)) = a^(-2) - a^(-4) + a^(-6) - ...

eq1 - eq2 is equivalent to eq1 + (-eq2), the following:

eq1: a/(a+a^(-1)) = 1 - a^(-2) + a^(-4) - a^(-6) + ...

and

-eq2: - a^(-1)/(a+a^(-1)) = - a^(-2) + a^(-4) - a^(-6) - ...

thus eq1 - eq2 = 1 - 2a^(-2) + 2a^(-4) - 2a^(-6) + ...
taking out common factor of 2 after the one: eq1 - eq2 = 1 - 2(a^(-2) + a^(-4) - a^(-6) + ... )
notice how this is equal to 1 - 2 * eq2

thus

a/(a+a^(-1)) - a^(-1)/(a+a^(-1))    =    1 - 2a^(-1)/(a+a^(-1)).

Testing with arbitrary values affirms this.

Are there any packages I could use that would accept negative exponents? Perhaps one that computes it with the calc package, and can deal with the recursion? If not, all I need is to be able to write the numbers in myself. Or if we're feeling daring, how to make one myself?

I could simply do each operation of the long division line by line, but that would be pretty boring.

Comment: @Marijn No, you have misunderstood. I need a long division symbol, compatible with negative exponents. An example of algebraic long division can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lT00iLntFc .

Comment: Most computers don't like infinite loops.  If doing it is boring, write your own package.